# push UIViewController from within child UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a `UINavigationController` stack. One of the `UIViewControllers` in this stack has a `UIButton` that adds a Child `UIViewController` to achieve a modal appearance (it is a menu that has blurred, semi-transparent background). The code is below and is working great.

```
        var childVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Extra") as! UIViewController
        childVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)

        self.navigationController?.addChildViewController(childVC)
        self.navigationController?.didMoveToParentViewController(childVC)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
```

But inside the Child `UIViewController` I need to push a UIViewController on top of stack i.e. on the Parent UIViewController. I have tried a bunch of things but the best I can get is it bringing up a blank screen with `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` - this runs the code in the next UIViewController (e.g. it prints to console) but obviously has the problem of showing a blank screen. I have also tried         `self.parentViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController`

**EDIT:** also, if I print out the stacks         `println(self.navigationController!.viewControllers)` in the `viewDidLoad` of the top UIViewController i.e. the one showing up blank. It prints as expected: the first `UIViewController`, the modal `UIViewController` and the top `UIViewController`.

Comment: Have you tried to push the view controller with self.presentingViewController?

Comment: @TedHuinink yeah that's not what I'm looking for. As expected, that presents the `UIViewController` but not on the stack. However, it is worth noting that the status bar is blank/all white when I do that (when I try `pushViewController` the whole screen is white). Thanks for comment!